# In de Sitter space, does the cosmic horizon change its shape for fast-moving observer?

Tags: general-relativity, event-horizon, de-sitter-spacetime

If an observer moves at a speed close to the speed of light, will the horizon deviate from spherical shape?

If no, will it be the same horizon as for stationary observer (at the same position)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unless the observer is accelerating.  A linearly accelerating observer will perceive a non-spherical Rindler horizon at minimum distance $c^2/a$, where $a$ is proper acceleration. This Rindler horizon will be closer than the cosmic horizon as long as the observer's proper acceleration is greater than $c^2/R_u$, where $R_u$ is the radius of the observable Universe.

Comment: And this Rindler horizon will not be spherical, yes?

Answer (score 1):

De Sitter space is a maximally symmetric space, which means that all its points and all 4-velocities at each point are equivalent and could be related via an isometry. This means that any inertial observer will experience de Sitter space in the same way, in particular cosmological horizon for each observer would have the same geometry.

Cosmological horizons are observer dependent and so different observers would have different horizons even when their worldlines intersect.

Comment: Does this mean I and my friend have different horizons?

Comment: I do not know. Presumably you & friend are non-inertial observers. What would be yours & friend's worldlines in the far future? If you end up on the same asymptotic trajectory the horizon would be the same.